# MySQL Insert if select is null to avoid bidirectional duplicates

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm building a db to hold friendships between users of my app.
The server I use to communicate with the MySQL instance is written using Node.js (Express).

My table 'friendships' consists mainly of two INTs which correspond (foreign keys) to user ids.
I want to avoid bidirectional duplicates ( 1,2 vs. 2,1) so I need to write a query which does the following:

```
INSERT INTO friendships f (id_1, id_2) VALUES (?, ?) IF (SELECT * FROM friendships s WHERE s.id_1=? AND s.id_2=?) IS NULL ;
```

Obviously this one doesn't really work. And of course I would have the last two question marks have opposite values compared to the first ones, and a UNIQUE key on the ids (id_1, id_2).

The usual answer for these kind of questions is "just order your ids by size to avoid duplicates" and it's a good answer. But in my case, I want to keep record of who sent the friend request (and who approved), without using any extra variables (and extra queries).

Also, I don't want to use code for this, in order to avoid "concurrent" problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this with a trigger that does the check.  Some other databases have functional indexes, indexes on computed columns, or check constraints that help implement this functionality.

If you want to do the check in the `insert`, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO friendships(id_1, id_2) 
    select new1, new2
    from (select ? as new1, ? as new2) t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from friendships f
                      where f.id_1 = new2 and f.id_2 = new1
                     );
```

You should also have a unique index on `id_1` and `id_2`:

```
create unique index idx_friendsships_id1_id2 on (id_1, id_2);
```

EDIT:

The basic query is:

```
INSERT INTO friendships(id_1, id_2) 
    select ?, ?
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1
                      from friendships f
                      where f.id_1 = ? and f.id_2 = ?
                     );
```

But you have to get the arguments in the right order, so the earlier method is less prone to error.

Comment: Yes it works!:)
Isn't it possible to do with less 'select'? Wouldn't the query take longer this way?  
And yes unique index is needed, I edited the question to remind that..  

Oh and fix your answer near the end, replace "and new1" with "=new1"

Comment: @guy_m . . . I wouldn't worry about performance for a single row update.  This will just basically be doing an index lookup for the `not exists`.  The reason for the extra layer of `select` is so you can pass the parameters in only once.

Comment: yeah passing parameters only once is cool:) Can you please show me how I'd do it if passing them twice is ok by me? Sometimes I prefer short/simple queries over complicated ones. Thx